# Nesting project file name into layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

Is there any way to automatically take information from the project file name into several boxes on a layout in QGIS?

For example, if I had a file name of `"185.005R1 - Geology Map.qgz"` how could I split it into separate textboxes, e.g. the Drawing number (`"185.005"`), the title (`"Geology Map"`), and the Revision number (`"1"`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following expressions. They are based on regular expressions, so will be nice and tolerant of slight differences in format:

For Drawing Number:

```
regexp_substr(@project_filename,'(.*?)R')
```

For Revision Number

```
regexp_substr(@project_filename,'.*?R\\s*(.*?)\\s*-')
```

Title:

```
regexp_substr(@project_filename,'-\\s*(.*)\\.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the project variables @project_basename together with substring in the expression builder if your string has always the same structure. If not you can try it with regex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another method which worked using expression is as the following:

For Drawing Number:

```
regexp_substr( @project_filename ,'\\d+.\\d+')
```

[image]

For Revision Number

```
regexp_substr( @project_filename ,'\\d{3}.\\d{3}\\D+(\\d+)')
```

[image]

For Title:

```
regexp_substr( @project_filename ,'- (\\D+).qgz')
```

[image]